# How to push different projects to repositories of different GitHub accounts?

Tags: xcode, git, macos, github, repository

I have 2 accounts on GitHub.
I want to be able to push particular projects to repositories of one account and some to another GitHub account.

How to make it happen?
I am on Mac OS.

Answer (score 1):

This article https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-configure-git-username-and-email/ helped me solve this problem.
Answering to my own question after a while.

Helpful Extracts from the article:

> Git allows you to set **a global** *and* **per-project** username and email address. You can set or change your git identity using the `git config` command. Changes only affect future commits. The name and email associated with the commits you made prior to the change are not affected.

> Setting **Global** Git Username and Password.
> The global git username and password are associated with commits on **all** repositories on your system that don’t have repository-specific values. To set your global commit name and email address run the `git config` command with the `--global` option:

```
$ git config --global user.name "Your Name"
$ git config --global user.email "youremail@yourdomain.com"
```

> Setting Git Username and Password for a **Single Repository**. If you want to use a different username or email address for a specific repository, run the `git config` command **without** the `--global` option from **within the repository directory**. Let’s say you want to set a repository-specific username and email address for a stored in the `~/Code/myapp directory`. Navigate to the folder needed.

```
$ cd ~/Code/myapp
```

> Set a Git username and email address:

```
git config user.name "Your Name"
git config user.email "youremail@yourdomain.com"
```

That is it!
Now if you make any commits and changes, it will be held under the specified name and email.

Answer (score 0):

Please generate a ssh key for your mac machine following github official doc https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

Then add it in your both github accounts. Then clone your repository using ssh.

```
git clone git@github.com:<git_username>/<repo_name>.git
```

After that when you push your code in your remote repository, your code will be pushed specific account repository.

Comment: I am sorry but still it is not clear. The reason I may have not understood is that what is SSH key? Why to generate? What does it do? If you could, can you explain that to me?

Comment: SSH key is an access credential in the ssh protocol. When you generate a ssh key of your machine add it in your github account, github will identify your machine with this ssh key. After that any push from your machine doesn't need any further authentication(username/password).

Comment: OK, I generated an SSH key; I understood its usage. 
Connected that SSH key to my GitHub accounts... 

But how then will I be able for example to push my iOS projects from Xcode to my 1 GitHub account, and for example to push university projects to my university GitHub account?

Comment: If you have already an existing repository in github, then you can add that repository as remote in your local repository.
`$ git remote -v` [to verify your remote]

`$ git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git`

`$ git pull`

`$ git push origin master`